# How to get the next predicted value from an extrapolation (linear regression?) using a set of data in a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, extrapolation

sorry but the title is not clear enough because I didn't know how to describe it with few words.

As you can see in the image I have used interp1d to graphically "predict" the value of y when x=7.
What I'm trying to do is to predict another value of y when x+1 (8) and so on any time the size of X grows up till the last value of the dataset is reached(let's say 100) using a for loop?. like

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
[ 4470.76 25465.72 25465.72 25465.72 21480.59 20024.53]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[ 4470.76 25465.72 25465.72 25465.72 21480.59 20024.53 15487.45]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[ 4470.76 25465.72 25465.72 25465.72 21480.59 20024.53 15487.45 25654.14]

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[ 4470.76 25465.72 25465.72 25465.72 21480.59 20024.53 15487.45 25654.14 54874.22]
...
```

Any ideas, please?
edit:  [csv_file](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/6cfb037894a560de8c6b17968ee06349/df.csv)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import scipy.stats as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize': (18, 5)})
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Load dataset
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=";", index_col = 'date')
df = df[['pow']]

# Reset index
df = df.reset_index()
df = df[['date', 'pow(+)']]
df.head(10)

X = np.array(pd.to_datetime(df['date'].index.values+1, format='%Y-%m-%d'), dtype=int)#.reshape((-1, 1))
X = X[:6]
y = np.array(df['pow(+)'], dtype=float)#.reshape(-1, 1)
y = y[:6]

print (X)
print (y)

f = interp1d(X, y, fill_value = "extrapolate")

#start, stop , nber of samples to generate, If True, stop is the last sample
X_new = np.linspace(0, 7, num=8, endpoint=True)

plt.plot(X, y, 'o', X_new, f(X_new), '-')
plt.legend(['data', 'linear'], loc='best')
plt.show()
#print('\n')
#print("X shape:", X.shape)
#print("y shape:", y.shape)
```

[image: output]

Comment: post csv data or df data

Comment: edited: csv file added

Answer (score 0):

This is not simple task, you need to:

1. find single or mix of functions that will fit you data
2. in this example find trend of you data with line fitting
3. set proper bounds for each parameter for complex function
4. predict new value based of fitted parameters

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
x_data = np.array(pd.to_datetime(df['date'].index.values+1, format='%Y-%m-%d'), dtype=int)
y_data = np.array(df['pow'], dtype=float)

# normalise data
y_data = (y_data - np.min(y_data))/ np.max(y_data)


# find data trend
def line_function(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b


# fit function
parameters_line, covariance_line = curve_fit(line_function, x_data, y_data, method='lm')


# define fitting function
def fit_function(x, A, t, fi, c, d):
    return A*np.sin(x*t + fi)**2 + c*x + d


# set bounds for each parameter
param_bounds = ([0, 0, 0, -1, 0], [2, (2*np.pi/600), 10, parameters_line[0], 10])
# fit function
parameters_fit, covariance_fit = curve_fit(fit_function, x_data, y_data,bounds=param_bounds , method='trf')
A, t, fi, c, d = [value for value in parameters_fit]

# predict new value
x_predict = 900
y_predict = fit_function(x_predict, A, t, fi, c, d)

# plot data
x_fit_data = np.linspace(-100, 1000, 1000)
y_fit_data = fit_function(x_fit_data, A, t, fi, c, d)
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, '.')
plt.plot(x_fit_data, y_fit_data, '-')
y_line_fit_data = line_function(x_fit_data, parameters_line[0], parameters_line[1])
plt.plot(x_fit_data, y_line_fit_data, '--')

plt.plot(x_predict, y_predict, 'o')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]